# ADB Shell is not displaying logs continously

Tags: android, logging, adb, logcat

I am trying to debug a Yocto project. I have flashed cpp binaries on some device.
Now I my trying to display logs using below adb command

```
 adb shell tail -f main.log
```

The problem i'm facing is that logs are not displayed continuously.I have to cancel and again start to print further log statements.

Anyone can help me in this ?

Comment: How this question is related to C++ programming language?

Comment: Sorry actually the complete project was in cpp , i missed that part. Updated my question now

Comment: Just a guess: If program is restarted is the log deleted and then re-created? In such a case `tail -f` will continue to display the now deleted file.